# JUnit Parameterized tests not running in isolation with Mockito, Spring, Reflection and AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, reflection, junit, mockito

I have the below test class, which has been stripped to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:restful-service-test-context.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ResftulServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("failedAspectTestMessage")
    private String failedAspectTestMessage;

    @Autowired
    private ProviderService ProviderService;

    private String methodName;
    private Set valuesToReturnByMock;
    private TestContextManager testContextManager;

    public ResftulServiceTest(String methodName, String[] valuesToReturnByMockArray) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.valuesToReturnByMock = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(valuesToReturnByMockArray));
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection values() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { "getCountries", new String[] { "GB", "US" } }, });
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpSpringContext() throws Exception {
        testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetValues_Fail_MyException() throws Exception {
        Method methodInProviderService = ProviderService.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

        Mockito.when(methodInProviderService.invoke(ProviderService))
                .thenThrow(new MyException(failedAspectTestMessage, StatusCodeType.ERROR));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetValues_Fail_Exception() throws Exception {
        Method methodInProviderService = ProviderService.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

        Mockito.when(methodInProviderService.invoke(ProviderService))
                .thenThrow(new AspectException(failedAspectTestMessage));
    }
}
```

If I run each of the tests separately, they work fine. However, if I run all of them, `testGetValues_Fail_Exception` fails on the Mockito line with error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com<obfuscated>.ResftulServiceTest.testGetValues_Fail_Exception(ResftulServiceTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.<obfuscated>.MyException: FAILED_ASPECT_TEST_MESSAGE
    ... 40 more
```

If I replace the `.thenThrow` in `testGetValues_Fail_MyException` with `.thenReturn`, it all works fine, so at some point the isolation is being broken. **How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: have you tried `Mockito.reset()`? Also, how you are setting up the mocking seems really odd to me. When you call `invoke` you are actually calling the method. I don't believe instances of `Method` are mocks.

Comment: I have tried Mockito.reset() now but no luck. However, I think you are correct, the way it fails suggests it is actually calling the method in the when statement. Any idea how I could do this some other way while still using reflection?

Comment: I made a rushed mistake and just tried to call reset with no parameters, which for some reason is valid. Doing Mockito.reset(methodInProviderService) actually solved it. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: It is valid because `reset` takes var args `(...)` which allows for 0 or more arguments of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Mockito.reset()` passing your mock. Usually this is done to prevent interaction between test. It resets the previously configured behavior of the mock. However, in your case I cannot give more details as you are using an unusual combination of `Parameterized` with Spring context and `DirtiesContext`.

Comment: Just to note, DirtiesContext was no longer necessary after adding Mockito.reset().